# How to call this if statement 3 times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How do I call this statement where I had to have 3 intvalue of  2 in order to get the NSLOG "MOO"? Right now as I draw a initvalue of 2 once it will give me NSLog moo ,but I want it where I have to draw it 3 times to get NSLog "MOO". Any tips?

```
 if ([[dictionary valueForKey:[cowssShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCow]] intValue] == 2)
 {
      NSLog(@"MOO");
 }
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`?

Comment: Already did java. And this line of code I did first doesn't work because it will call nslog moo 3 times rather than having 3 intvalues of 2 then calling moo.

Comment: Maybe you should have stayed at it for longer than 15 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean, can this code actually work?

Comment: I mean you should have learned to program before you jumped into Objective-C.

Comment: I have over 3 video game apps on the app store. If you know this so much put up or shut up. Because seems I did your code before, but it didn't work.

Comment: I have 40 years programming experience and you apparently don't know how to write a simple if statement.  Yes, you've maybe been able to modify example programs to produce some "apps", but you don't really know what you're doing -- you're just feeling your way in the dark.  (This is first semester stuff, for crying out loud.)

Comment: Bro, you are saying you are 50 years old or above? Damn! You are an old man. And fyi, this doesn't work with my situation.

Comment: Yep, I'm old and grouchy.  Started with FORTRAN, learned BASIC, assembler, a bit of COBOL, APL, PL/I, C, C++, several proprietary languages, Java, and, of course, Objective-C.  Objective-C is not a simple language (in fact, one of the ugliest I've dealt with), and it's far better to start with something relatively "clean" such as Java.

Comment: (Hint:  Write down what it is you want to do, in English (or whatever language).  Then figure out how to translate that into your target language.  Think before you write.)

Comment: Yeah, one flaw your method doesn't work with my situation obviously. And I am only few months in objective c and already getting the hand of it. Especially Xcode app development. I am not going to be decent until probably over a year but hey who is good when they first start? All you can do is research,read books,and push yourself. And reason why I started with Objective c is to make iPhone apps and mac apps in the future because that is where I want to have a career in. And yes I tried your method btw.It gives me 2 situations. One it calls moo 3 times in a row.And 2 it calls deal,moo 3 times.

Comment: Write it out IN MORE DETAIL.  Step by step.

Comment: Oh btw, is fortran that punchcard bs?

Comment: Punch cards will rise again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First initialise

```
int count=0;
```

then

```
 if ([[dictionary valueForKey:[cowssShuffled objectAtIndex:currentCow]] intValue] == 2)
     {
          count++;
          if(count==2)
          {
              NSLog(@"MOO");
          }
     }
```

Comment: More like `if (count == 3)`, non? And then reset the counter.

Comment: I believe this works, thank you.

Comment: shoot, just found out it doesn't work, actually. Yep hot licks is right!. Do you know the solution Hot Licks?